# PL/SQL "no data found"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting an error "no data found" when I call the following PL/SQL function

```
FUNCTION get_Deployment_Status(i_deploymentId deployments.pk%type)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    o_status varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct Status
    into   o_status
    FROM   deployments
    WHERE  Pk=i_deploymentId; 

    return o_status;
END;
```

I pass the deploymentid which is a number and I expect the status to be returned as a string. Is there a better way to do that? why I am getting that error?

Comment: You may handle `no_data_found` in an `exception` if you're sure that only one row is returned from the select. But, why are you using `distinct`? Does the select statement return more than one row?

Comment: Is column `PK` in database table `DEPLOYMENTS` the sole primary key column for that table?

Comment: Yes PK is the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following options. Read comments within the code.

**Option #1:**

```
FUNCTION get_deployment_status (i_deploymentid deployments.pk%TYPE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   o_status  VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   -- This option will return O_STATUS if something is found. If not, NO_DATA_FOUND
   -- EXCEPTION section will handle it.
   -- You most probably don't need DISTINCT nor TOO_MANY_ROWS handling as it appears that
   -- you're dealing with a primary key column; are you? If not, well, you'll have to 
   -- handle that option as well.
   SELECT status
     INTO o_status
     FROM deployments
    WHERE pk = i_deploymentid;

   RETURN o_status;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
END;
```

**Option #2:**

```
FUNCTION get_deployment_status (i_deploymentid deployments.pk%TYPE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   o_status  VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   -- This option will return NULL into O_STATUS if there's nothing found.
   -- It won't raise the NO_DATA_FOUND exception. 
   -- Just like above, if it is a primary key column involved in the WHERE 
   -- clause, you shouldn't care whether MAX will return correct value or not,
   -- because - if it exists - it will be the only value.
   SELECT MAX (status)
     INTO o_status
     FROM deployments
    WHERE pk = i_deploymentid;

   RETURN o_status;
END;
```